# What's the size of 'field data' in Elasticsearch for a field with doc_values turned on

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the mapping like this:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "mydoc": {
      "properties": {
         "createdAt": {
         "type": "date",
         "format": "date_optional_time",
         "doc_values": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After indexing can I find out the size of the 'field data' for this field on HDD? Elasticsearch docs say that with enabling `doc_values: true` they build 'field data' on during index process.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think so. With nodes' stats you can see fielddata usage, but I don't think you can see `doc_values` size.

Answer (score 0):

There is no endpoint to know exactly the difference between fielddata and doc_values.

The only way to find out is to index the same data 2 times : once with `doc_values` enabled, and once with `fielddata`.

With the data provided is this [blogpost](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-storage-the-true-story) about storage in ElasticSearch, you can see there is roughly 20-30% increase of the index size when doc_values are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Since doc values are stored in [`dvd` and `dvm` Lucene files](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene49/Lucene49DocValuesFormat.html), you could simply compute the size of those files on disk with the following command.

```
ls -laR $ES_HOME/data/* | grep "dv[d|m]" | awk '{ total += $5 }; END { print total }'
```

- `ls -laR` will simply list all files in your ES data folder
- `grep` will catch only the `dvd` and `dvm` files
- `awk` will fetch the 5th column (i.e. the file size in bytes) and add it to the `total` variable
- finally the `total` is printed out and should represent the total size in bytes of all your doc values footprint on disk.